# Eager loading for one to many to one in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a database schema just like below:

[image: ER Model]

Here is the code that I need to do eager loading for my data:

```
var item = db.Course
    .Include(p => p.CourseInstructor)
    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.CourseId == courseId);

if (item == null)
{
    return NotFound();
}

return (from p in item.CourseInstructor
        select p.Instructor).ToList();
```

All I can get are the `null` on the `p.Instructor` navigation property.

I was tried to use `ThenInclude`, but I don't know how to code it right.

[image: Wrong trial]

How can I made this code works as expected to get the full `Person` data using Eager loading technique?

Comment: your db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled is true? Can you confirm?

Comment: Are you looking for all instructors given a course id? Try `var instructors = db.CourseInstructors.Include(p => p.Instructor).Where(p => p.CourseId == courseId).ToList();`

Comment: @LeBigCat This is EF Core so there is no lazy loading.

Comment: @LeBigCat I don't want the lazy loading enabled.

Comment: @GabrielLuci The Lazy loading feature was introduced in EF Core 2.1.  Check this out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading

Comment: @SteveGreene I was looking for include multiple levels.

Comment: Why? In this use case it is not needed.

Comment: @SteveGreene In my use case, it do needed.

Comment: You want a list of instructors for a course, correct?

Comment: @WillHuang Good to know! (about lazy loading)

Comment: @SteveGreene Yes, including the properties of the Instructor ( `Person` table ).

Answer (score 0):

I finally realize that the `ThenInclude` has two signatures.  For the `navigationPropertyPath` parameter, these two signature are different:

1. `Expression<Func<CourseInstructor, Person>>`
2. `Expression<Func<ICollection<CourseInstructor>, ICollection<CourseInstructor>>`

In the Visual Studio 2017, only one signature will be selected to providing IntelliSense suggestion.  In my VS2017, the second signature will be selected.  So that I can't see any suggestion from the first one signature.

The following screenshot is the "RIGHT" signature of my intention, but VS2017 won't choose this one.

[image]

In my case, all I need to do is just enter the `navigationPropertyPath` as I want.  When you enter the right property name without IntelliSense help.  The error check will pass and your project is able to build correctly!

Here is the final code I wrote below:

```
var item = db.Course
    .Include(p => p.CourseInstructor)
        .ThenInclude(i => i.Instructor)
    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.CourseId == courseId);

if (item == null)
{
    return NotFound();
}

return (from p in item.CourseInstructor
        select p.Instructor).ToList();
```

It just works as expected.

---

This is known bug tracked here: [Completion missing members of lambda parameter in fault tolerance case · Issue #8237 · dotnet/roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/8237)

Comment: Your exact scenario is laid out here. Much simpler code IMO. https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/03/12/avoid-many-to-many-mappings-in-orms/

Comment: @SteveGreene EF Core doesn't support Many-to-Many relationship.  Your link is talk about EF6.

Comment: It would be pretty useless without many-to-many :) All that changed was you have to explicitly define the table. ["...you can represent a many-to-many relationship by including an entity class for the join table..."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships)

Comment: @SteveGreene I see "many-to-many relationships" is on the way.  I hope EF Core 3.0 can see it.  :) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/roadmap

Comment: No, it is already there - your code is evidence of that :) In EF 6 the bridge table was implicitly created, in EF Core you define it explicitly (CourseInstructor). I guess you could argue it is 2 one-to-manies, but that is how it was in EF 6 too.

Comment: @SteveGreene Actually I don't use "Code First" approach in my project.  I was create DB first then scaffold all the "Code First" models and dbcontext.  I got your point anyway. ;)